# How to change layout(Master Page) from controller in mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the layout of application, in my application there are two type of user Admin and Member, from admin member can login. I want to change the layout to member when login as member from admin.
Here is my code

```
public ActionResult UserLogin(string email, int type)
{
    #region SignOut Admin First
    //signout First
    if (Session["id"] != null)
    {
        UserLogBL ul = new UserLogBL();
        UserLog lg = ul.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]));
        lg.logout = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        ul.Update(lg);
    }
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    LmsSession.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    #endregion

    //getting user detail
    LearnerBL learnerBL = new LearnerBL();
    int id = learnerBL.GetIdBYName(email);
    Learner learner = learnerBL.GetByID(id);
    if (learner != null)
    {
        String role = LoginUser(learner);
        if (string.Equals(role.ToLower(), "admin"))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminDashboard");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "LearnerMyLearning");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Comment: In the respective views you can set `@Layout="~/Views/Shared/LayoutNameHere.cshtml"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the respective views you can set the layout that the view should use.

```
@Layout="~/Views/Shared/LayoutNameHere.cshtml"
```